# How to localize MacOS folder name?

Tags: macos, localization, macos-monterey

There was a document from Apple to tell how to localize folder name at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemAdvancedPT/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory.html).

But on MacOS Monterey it doesn't work anymore.

Have any other method to do this?

I know a way that changes the file in `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations/xxxx.lproj/`

But at now it is very difficult to change the system file in MacOS, even though I turn off the SIP.

Is there a `decent` way can do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow what is written in the documentation you reference, it actually works.

Make sure you create your folder with a .localized at the end of its name.
e.g. `MyFolder.localized`

And then under this folder, you have to create another folder named `.localized` under which you have to place your translations within `.strings` files

Hope this helps...